# Android: Calling service again not refreshing the data

Tags: android

I am developing an android app. in which users can update their personal information and on update when users wants to see their information I used to refresh the data in users table (that is recalling the service of users info and saving it in the users table). But the problem is it won't show me the new data. It only show the new data only when the user logouts from app. At logout I used to clear all the data from local db. So my question is why the new data not showing on calling the service againg and the old data not updated locally?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: are you using any timer to call your service/

Comment: @ Sreekanthss not setting any timer.